# Test spring application that comes with a blocking ApplicationRunner

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, asynchronous

I am writing a test of a Spring application. This application comes with an `ApplicationRunner` (let's call it `AppRunner`) which is bundled though an Autoconfiguration. And once called (i.e. Spring automatically call `AppRunner.run()`), this `AppRunner` will poll some kafka topic, block until it get a message, process it, then loop if no one called `stop()`.

Now, what I would want to do in the test, is start the application and "in parallel" execute the tests that push kafka message and check the output is valid.

But `AppRunner.run` is called before the @Test, and everything get stuck.

=> How should I run my test? Is is possible to configure spring (boot) test to run the `AppRunner` asynchronously?

This is not a web app, but I would expect that (tests of) Spring web apps to run asynchronously. Maybe there is a solution using a similar system (?).

Comment: Have you tried to define a mock bean of type ApplicationRunner inside your test class, and do `Mockito.doNothing().when(appRunner).run(any());` ?

Comment: I actually need the AppRunner, it is part of the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to override the AppRunner and override the run method to run asynchronously. Something like this:

```
public class AsyncAppRunner extends AppRunner {

    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    private Option<Future<?>> runningTask = Option.empty();

    public AsyncAppRunner(Dep1 dep1, Dep2, dep2 /*...*/) {
        super(dep1, dep2);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
        if(runningTask.isDefined()) throw new RuntimeException("already running");
        runningTask = Option.apply(executorService.submit(() -> super.run(args)));
    }

    void stopAndWait() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        if(runningTask.isDefined()){
            super.stop(); // method of the AppRunner that stop the infinite loop
            runningTask.get().get(1L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            runningTask = Option.empty();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("No task running");
        }
    }
}
```

And add this class to the SpringBootTest classes:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {..., AsynAppRunner.class })
public class MyAppTest {
    ...
```